# Java edge case collection hashmap iteration

Tags: java

I got this problem I need to return the key in a hashmap with the largest value, the trick here is that the method must account for edge case scenarios. I can also only use the above imports, so Map.Entry is not allowed. Collections.sort isn't etc. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Exercise {
    public static String findLargest(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
        // Enter code here
 if(that.isEmpty()) return "";
        Integer maxInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String maxCity = "";
        for(String entry : that.keySet()) {
            if (that.get(entry) != null && that.get(entry) < Integer.MAX_VALUE && that.get(entry) > Integer.MIN_VALUE && that.get(entry) > maxInt) {
                maxInt = that.get(entry);
                maxCity = entry;
            }
        }
        return maxCity;
    }

    public static void check(String largest, List<String> apples, List<Integer> size) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
            map.put(apples.get(i), size.get(i));
        }
        assert largest.equals(findLargest(map)) : "expected " + largest + " but was " + findLargest(map);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        check("Granny", Arrays.asList("Granny", "Eve", "Rose"), Arrays.asList(5, 1, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like an HW. So what have you tried and where are you stuck? Could you post code that compiles?

Comment: First thing to do: learn the value of whitespace to make your code more readable. Next, even without imports, you could still use `Map.Entry`. Next, what do you want to do if there are multiple keys for the same value? Or no values at all? (Those are the edge cases I'd be thinking about...)

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework, since otherwise imports are quite cheap :). Hint: what edge cases (cases on the edge between one decision and the other) do you think the teacher is talking about?

Comment: How would you find a max of anything? Do that.

Comment: I really can't use Map.Entry, doesn't compile given the imports. I know how you would normally find the max of a map but weird cases give errors, I'm going to try the case where multiple keys have the same value.

Comment: @Shifty Edit your question with the code you've tried

Comment: Question: Did they give you this method signature? Because if not, you should probably return the list of all maximal size

Comment: thats given we can only change the body.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really inefficient, but if you cannot add any other imports... it works. The first step is to find the maximum value among the integers and then for each of the keys, check if the `map.get(key).equals(max)`:

```
public static String findLargest(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
    //step 1
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i : map.values()) {
        max = Math.max(max, i);
    }
    //step 2        
    for (String str : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(str).equals(max)) {
            return str;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can do it in one pass if you loop through the entry set directly.

Comment: What if every number is negative? Then you would look for a max that doesn't even exists in the map.

Comment: I like the solution, but it isn't handling these edge cases that I have know what they are. "There was an exception:
java.lang.AssertionError"

Comment: You're right Tom, I changed the initial max value to Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: This edit makes it worse ... Now you would almost never find the real max value. You already selected the *maximum* value of integer as the initial value of `max`. How should `i` ever by larger than that?

Comment: An edge case I can think of is when there are more than one max values. But, your method cannot handle this case: it only returns one String

Comment: There is another extreme case: if the map is empty. And in that case the method returns null;

Comment: yea, i might need to compare them in some way. btw change your code back to max = 0;

Comment: As Tom suggested Integer.MIN_VALUE; is the correct solution: You do not need any import and works even with negative values (-10 > Integer.MIN_VALUE)

Comment: Alexis C. you cannot: You don't know you have found *the* max value until you have checked all entries

Comment: @nelly You can. You just need to update the max value and the max key according to the current one you set when iterating the entry set. This can be done in one pass of course.